# accordion menu by reading from xml file

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css, jquery-ui, menu

I am looking for an accordion menu code sample to load it from the xml file rather than hardcoding the file names in the mark-up. Can you please share the link if you are aware of any such menu controls? (something like the one at this link http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu/. it will be nice if I can pin it to the left as well)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific addon/code to do what you want; but, you could start out by processing the XML to produce the HTML markup, then just use one of the accordion menu addons to complete it.

It is difficult to provide you with a code sample or recommendations when you haven't shared the XML or any script.